# Is there a time when browsers will not support HTML4

Tags: browser, html

I want to know when the browsers will stop supporting HTML4. My customer has a website with a lot of frames and framesets and we have to plan the migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the major browsers have put out statements regarding HTML4 support end dates yet. However, if frames are a major part of your customer's website, I would suggest planning the migration sooner rather than later. Frames and framesets were not included in HTML5 "because using them damages usability and accessibility" ([HTML5 Differences from HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/)) so my guess is that, some point in the not-too-distant future, HTML4 support will begin to be phased out as the focus on accessibility increases.

You can keep an eye on browser plans for any HTML4-related changes, but as of now there doesn't seem to be anything in the works.

#### Firefox

- [Mozilla Press Center](https://blog.mozilla.org/press/)
- [Mozilla Blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/category/mozilla-news/)

#### Chrome

- [Google Developer Updates](https://developers.google.com/web/updates)

#### Opera

- [Opera Newsroom](https://press.opera.com/)

#### Edge

- [Microsoft Edge Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev)

#### Safari

- [Safari What's New page](https://developer.apple.com/safari/whats-new/)

#### Brave

- [Brave press releases](https://brave.com/press/)